# How to configure Windows Phone 8.0 Push notifications with HTTPS

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, https, push-notification

I want to set up an authenticated web service to send push notifications for Windows Phone 8 so i have followed this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941099%28v=vs.105%29.aspx but the notification channel returned by the api is always HTTP and not HTTPS as expected.
I've already worked with http push notifications on Windows Phone 8.0 and they work correctly.

I've followed the guide, even if the description refers to the old Windows Phone Dashboard.
I've purchased a new certificate associated with a CN = "util.example.com" and uploaded it in the "Services -> Push notifications" section of my application ("Test App WP") and the certificate is correctly recognized. Then i set up the cliend side code:

```
pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("ToastChannel", "util.example.com");              
pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
pushChannel.Open();
pushChannel.BindToShellToast();
....
....
private void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
{
    string channel = e.ChannelUri.ToString();
    //channel sent to our server
    .....
}
```

I have tested with debug and also publishing a Beta in the store for "Test App WP".
Also i tried restarting the phone and reinstalling the application but the result is the same.
What do i need to change to obtain an https notification channel?